# Center UILabel inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to show a `UILabel` with variable text length so I need it to be inside `UIScrollView`. Here is the result

[image]

the problem is when the text is short `UILabel` is sticking to the top and when I'm removing the top and bottom constraint and adding vertical center constraint I'm getting this errror

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: ScrollView need 6 (not 4) constraints. You should set leading-trailing-top-bottom and width-height, too

Comment: I know it so how can I center label inside ScrollView? I don't know the height because it's dynamic but width is fixed @QuocNguyen

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it careful. You can try to set the label's constraint to centerX, centerY and leading like this https://imgur.com/a/DfxoSvq

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: I couldn't test the solutions yet @AwaisFayyaz

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766400/center-uiview-vertically-in-scroll-view-when-its-dynamic-labels-are-small-enough[this is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766400/center-uiview-vertically-in-scroll-view-when-its-dynamic-labels-are-small-enough)

Comment: The secret really lies in the priorities. Good job !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have manage to do it by adding vertical center (priority 750) to container view. Added storyboard source below, it should scroll when you add longer text to label.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gQl-vh-MlV">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="647"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7JP-ij-rQ3">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="647"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hdc-ci-8Q2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="335" height="607"/>
                                                <string key="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </string>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="hdc-ci-8Q2" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="04P-f7-0B8"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="hdc-ci-8Q2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="AJ1-ka-NVH"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="hdc-ci-8Q2" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="Ihl-iD-MJL"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="hdc-ci-8Q2" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="Mea-zN-gQ6"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="250" id="5Pl-Zc-jKy"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="leading" id="6wk-HX-XUh"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="centerY" priority="750" id="a7o-hw-NRM"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" secondAttribute="trailing" id="hSU-wA-1v0"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="top" id="o0p-fH-VhV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7JP-ij-rQ3" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="width" id="wgf-e8-HLU"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Axy-dp-ZiJ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="gQl-vh-MlV" secondAttribute="trailing" id="LED-nS-Ba6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="gQl-vh-MlV" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="RS2-MF-Aya"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="gQl-vh-MlV" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="euc-Qn-E0q"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove top constraint and add **vertical center** and **horizontal center** constrains to your label so your label should be at center of scrollview